# Geometry on a space of polynomial functions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, cg.comp-geom, polynomials, fourier-analysis

> I am considering some geometric concepts in a space of functions.But I am not sure the concept I consider is already defined in some references.

Let $P_{1},...,P_{N}:\mathbb{F}_{2}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2}$ be functions with $ n $ variables

$dist (P,Q):=$ the number of input strings $x$ such that   $P(x)$ agrees with  $Q(x)$

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be a family of funcitons $\{P_{1},P_{2},...,P_{N}\}$

A subfamily $(m,\epsilon)-\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{P}$  is called  $(m,\epsilon)$-*colony* , if $(m,\epsilon)-\mathcal{C}$ is a subfamily of $\mathcal{P}$ such that for $some$ partial assignment to $m$ variables $\rho (m):{[n] \choose m} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ $\max\limits_{i,j}dist (P_{i}|_{\rho},P_{j}|_{\rho}) \leq \epsilon $

> My question : is there a reference or results on $any$ concepts relating with the above  $(m,\epsilon)$-*colony* ?

Comment: This seems related to Fourier analysis of the hypercube, more than any thing that has to do with geometry.